# Incrementally train a logistic regression?

Tags: logistic

Let's say I have a logistic regression model trained on the training dataset. Now new trained data, and I want to update the model according to the new data without learning everything from the beginning?

How could I do that? If possible could you provide Python or R code?

Comment: Sklearn has a partial_fit function for online learning.

Comment: +1 asking how to do it mathematically would be more on topic to CV.

Comment: What you're describing is called the [_Linear Perceptron_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) and probably exists in every neural network package you will find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementations of logistic regression typically use some form of gradient descent for optimization. Conceivably, therefore, you can perform updates by "remember" the state of the descent, and updating as new inputs come along. See, e.g., [Lazy Sparse Stochastic Gradient Descent
for
Regularized Mutlinomial Logistic Regression](https://lingpipe.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/lazysgdregression.pdf).

This is not the most mainstream approach to online classification, though. E.g., in `sklearn`, [different online classifiers are supported](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning). These work differently. They rely on some aggregating statistics that are relatively small, do not depend on the dataset size, and are amenable for online updates. For example, Naive Bayes just needs the statistics of empirical distributions for the classes.